# Python3 Determine if logarithm is "perfect," i.e., no remainder on float

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, logarithm

### Problem statement:

I am trying to determine if a logarithm is "perfect," i.e., there is no remainder. The issue I am having is that `math.log()` always returns a float.

I read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

### Here is my current solution:

```
import sys
import math


def is_even_log(argument, base):
    x = math.log(argument, base)  # yields float

    numerator, denominator = x.as_integer_ratio()

    print(
        f"numeratorerator: {numerator}, "
        f"denominatorominator: {denominator}")

    if numerator % denominator == 0:
        print(f"Log base {base} of {argument} is even")
        return True
    else:
        print(f"Log base {base} of {argument} is not even")
        return False


is_even_log(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

### Question

Just curious if anyone has better way to do this? I would imagine that I could access some property of the PyObject which indicates if there is a remainder or not.

Comment: Are `argument` and `base` integers? Is `base` positive? What is the meaning of “perfect” for a logarithm; does it mean that it is an integer? Or that it is rational? (The base-16 logarithm of 4 is exactly ½. Is that “perfect”?)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good points. I guess I should say that "perfect" is if arg and base are both integers and the log is an integer. I guess what I have written already is the cleanest. Perhaps I should just dig into the float implementation a little more. I suppose this really didn't have anything to do with logarithms and more to do with "How to determine if a floating has not remainder"

Answer (score 0):

You can round the logarithm to the nearest integer, and check if it's correct by exponentiating back up again:

```
def is_even_log(argument, base):
    return argument == base**round(math.log(argument, base))
```

Answer (score 0):

Log b in base i equals x is equivalent to  b equals i to the power x. So the code would be:

```py
def is_even_log(arg, base):
    x = math.log(arg, base)
    return arg == base ** int(x+1/2)
```

As the int function returns the truncation of a float,   `int(x+1/2)` returns the rounded number.
This solution works for integers (both arg and base) because in this case the if statement is a comparaison between integers

Testing the equality of floats is not recommended anyways because of the approximations.